# Selecting a text node to replace content

Tags: javascript

I have a `<template>` element I'm using to build up a bunch of checkboxes. It looks like this:

```
<template id="checky-tmpl">
  <label>
    <input type=checkbox value='value-goes-here'>label-goes-here
  <label>
</template>
```

and part of my vanilla-js looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < types.val.length; i++) {
  var tmpl = document.getElementById('checky-tmpl').content.cloneNode(true);
  tmpl.querySelector('input').value = types.val[i];
  // how do I target the 'label-goes-here' text node to set it to types.lab[i] ?
  document.getElementById('types-list').appendChild(tmpl);
}
```

How do I target the 'label-goes-here' text node to set it to types.lab[i]?

I know these don't work:

- `tmpl.querySelector('input').innerText = types.lab[i];`
  // error (`<input>` doesn't have a `innerText` property
- `tmpl.querySelector('label').innerText = types.lab[i];`
  // the entire contents of the `<label>` gets replaced, not just the text

I could insert a `<span></span>` element to hold the `label-goes-here` text, but that is sub-optimal (no drama, but code aesthetics give me pause).

I could use `tmpl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(types.lab[i]))` to stick the text in at the end of the node, but I'd have to remove the `label-goes-here` text from the template (no drama, but I like having my templates being self-documenting)

So ... I'd like to keep the `<template>` neat and tidy as it is, and to target the text node that is there and replace it with the least amount of shenanigans.

How?

Comment: plain js solutions preferred, no jquery

Comment: Nothing aesthetically wrong with adding a span to wrap the text

Comment: Adding a span whose only purpose for existing is to be targeted in the creation process and thence nevermore? Wrong ;-)

Comment: No .. not *"wrong"*. It's cleaner than targeting text nodes

Comment: I agree with @charlietfl it will be cleaner approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property of `input` element to target the immediately following TEXT_NODE element then set its [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) property

```js
var tmpl = document.getElementById('checky-tmpl').content.cloneNode(true);
tmpl.querySelector('input').value = "Yahooooooooo";

//nextSibling
tmpl.querySelector('input').nextSibling.nodeValue = "Yahooooooooo"

document.getElementById('types-list').appendChild(tmpl);
```

```html
<template id="checky-tmpl">
  <label>
    <input type=checkbox value='value-goes-here'>label-goes-here
  <label>
</template>
<div id="types-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating the `childNodes` and checking for `Node.TEXT_NODE`

```
[].slice.call(tmpl.querySelector('label').childNodes).forEach( function( element ){
   if ( element.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ) //check for text node here
   {
      console.log( element.nodeValue ); //this shows the value of text node 
      element.nodeValue = ""; //new value assignment 
   }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var tmpl = document.getElementById('checky-tmpl').content.cloneNode(true);
[].slice.call(tmpl.querySelector('label').childNodes).forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && element.nodeValue.trim().length > 0) //check for text node here
  {
    //console.log(element.nodeValue); //this shows the value of text node 
    element.nodeValue = "New Value"; //new value assignment 
  }
});
document.getElementById('types-list').appendChild(tmpl);
```

```html
<template id="checky-tmpl">
  <label>
    <input type=checkbox value='value-goes-here'>label-goes-here
  </label>
</template>
<div id="types-list"></div>
```